# GlassFish Installation error

Tags: glassfish-embedded

I have installed NetBeans 7.1.1 . I had installed Tomcat intially and Glassfish was removed f . But I need to develop some Enterprise applications . Hence I have separately download and installed Glassfish 3.1 successfully. When i run in localhost:8080 it shows that GlassFish server is running . But When I go to New Projects->Java EE -> Enterprise Application ->.. after filling the project location folder  details details it shows the message

> No servers are registered in the IDE. To register a server, click the "Add..." button.

It asks me to add  Glassfish server again. 
Even if I install it says Cant add a glassfish server instance...

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running? This sounds familiar to another issue that used to be around Windows.

This might be a brute solution, but have considered just upgrading to Netbeans 7.2 and doing a complete reinstall? You should be able to migrate your settings fairly simply I think. Install the EE packet right away, and everything should be there for you: http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html